# Linked file in PHP not opening

Tags: php

I have developed a code..i have created a from and in action i m opeing another file insert.php.however the submit query button does nothing and i am stuck at the same page.here is my code.

```
    <head>
    <script language="javascript" src="calendar.js"></script>
    </head>

    <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="sm_sample"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="sample"; // Table name
    $theDate;
    // Connect to server and select database.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    ?>

    <html>
    <body>





    Date<form action="somewhere.php" method="post">
    <?php
    //get class into the page
    require_once('classes/tc_calendar.php');

    //instantiate class and set properties
    $myCalendar = new tc_calendar("date1", true);
    $myCalendar->setIcon("images/iconCalendar.gif");
    $myCalendar->setdate(date('d'), date('m'), date('Y'));

    //output the calendar
    $myCalendar->writeScript();   
    ?>

    <?php
    $theDate = isset($_REQUEST["date1"]) ? $_REQUEST["date1"] : "";

    ?> 
    <br />








    <form method="post" action="insert.php">
    <br />Source<br /><select input name="source">

    <option value="Blogs">Blogs</option>
    <option value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="Google Buzz">Google Buzz</option>
    <option value="Google Plus">Google Plus</option>
    <option value="LinkedIn">LinkedIn</option>
    <option value="Twitter">Twitter</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
    <option value="UNKNOWN">UNKNOWN</option>

    </select>
    <br /><br />
    Username<br /><input type="text" name="username" />
    <br /><br />
    Location<br /><select input name="location">

    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Hongkong">Hongkong</option>
    <option value="UAE">UAE</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
    <option value="UNKNOWN">UNKNOWN</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />

    Category<br /><select input name="category">

    <option value="User Banking Experience">User Banking Experience</option>
    <option value="Credit/Debit Card">Credit/Debit Card</option>
    <option value="Customer Care">Customer Care</option>
    <option value="Staff Behavior">Staff Behavior</option>
    <option value="Others">Others</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    Complaint<br /><input type="text" name="complaint" />
    <br /><br />
    Status<br /><select input name="status">

    <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
    <option value="In Process">In Process</option>
    <option value="Resolved">Resolved</option>
    <option value="Insufficient Information">Insufficient Information</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />








    </form>
    </select>
    <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: ...and your form action is `somewhere.php`, not `insert.php`, which is just a plain link.

Comment: ... and the `<head>` should be inside `<html>`.

Comment: Run the HTML through a validator. You have some serious problems there.

Comment: @Jeremy: actually it's there, but close to the bottom: `<form action="somewhere.php" method="post">`

Comment: heh it is now.  wasn't before.

Comment: but i m using a different form for insert.php

Comment: @Jeremy: yep ^^ and now another form too: `<form method="post" action="insert.php">`. Over and out.

Comment: we can use form inside a form right??

Answer (score 1):

You can't have embedded `<form>` tags. They should be separated like so:

```
<form action="1.php">
<!-- fields and so forth -->
<input type="submit">
</form>

<form action="2.php">
<!-- fields for a second form -->
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: ya it exists..its for the calender feature

Answer (score 0):

This is really poorly formed HTML.  I think you need to study the language and basic constructs a bit.  There are really too many things wrong with this to give you a correct "answer" without gathering your requirements and rewriting it.

Comment: :i know.. :(
i am new to html n php...anyways if you are talking about the date part then its copied but still insert.php shud open even if it shows some error regarding the date part

Comment: I don't think you're understanding how html forms work.  This is severely hampering your ability to write functional html; unfortunately this is not the forum for education of that nature.  I strongly recommend you walk yourself some online educational documents regarding web page life cycles.... and no, forms inside forms will have issues, for obvious reasons if you understand the concepts behind them.